# Did the winners of the "golden ball dream team" received a real physical golden ball award made of gold?

Tags: football

France Football this year gave an award called "the golden ball dream team" to the best players in each position of all time in soccer. This is different to what they do each year, where they award the best soccer player of the year with a real physical golden ball award made of gold. If this time it was a physical award, they should have made 11 balls made of gold for each player. Players like Messi and Cristiano who received the golden ball of the year in previous years uploaded a photo with a golden ball. But players like Xavi or Maldini who never received a golden ball of the year didnt upload one. Also Messi uploaded another photo with his 6 former golden balls. This makes me think that the golden ball photo Messi and Cristiano uploaded is a golden ball of the year award, and that this time they didnt receive a physical golden ball made of gold. Is this so?

Did the winners of the "golden ball dream team" received a real physical golden ball award made of gold?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand, no. [It was announced,](https://blog.lequipe.fr/communiques/the-ballon-dor-will-not-be-awarded-in-2020/) that the trophy will not be awarded this year:

> As the organizer of the Ballon d’Or, the Group L’Équipe, to which France Football belongs, decided not to award the most prestigious individual trophy there is in 2020.

So, no, the final Ballon d'Or dream team will not receive the trophy. It makes sense as the process for dream team is very different. It'd be unfair to give them the same award they give "regular" Ballon d'Or winners.

P.S. To make it absolutely clear, the Ballon d'Or is gilded brass, not pure gold ([Mellerio dits Meller](https://mellerio.fr/en/les-trophees/)):

> In pyrite and gilded brass, it reproduces to scale a real football, on which the name of the winner is directly engraved.

Answer (score -2):

Lionel Messi, crowned in 2019, will hold the Ballon d'Or France Football title one more year. France Football said that in july ([french article](https://www.francefootball.fr/news/Il-n-y-aura-pas-de-ballon-d-or-france-football-en-2020/1153942)). Messi won 6 times in 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2015 and 2019.

So the winners of the "golden ball dream team" will not receive a real physical golden ball award

Comment: Bklups, I'm not sure what this has to do with the question - your first sentence just talks about Messi holding onto the Ballon for a year, which is true, but what does it have to do with the dream team being awarded, or not awarded, a new trophy?

Comment: There were two questions in one. @Pablo said _Messi uploaded another photo with his 6 former golden balls_ I answered that Messi already had 6 golden balls and so in fact **"golden ball dream team" will not receive a real physical golden ball award**

Comment: I think the actual question is: `Did the winners of the "golden ball dream team" received a real physical golden ball award made of gold?` - I don't think your answer addresses that.  The bit about the past golden ball trophies was just OP's explanation of why they're asking.

Comment: @Joe I think OP's trying to say that Messi is one of the winners and he doesn't have a *seventh* Ballon d'Or. This proves that he didn't receive the trophy as a member of dream team.